# Belize visa on arrival from the western border

Tags: borders, visas-on-arrival, belize

I am entering Belize from it western border with Guatemala. I have USA multiple entry visa, which I know means I get I can get a Belize visa on arrival (with 50 USD fee). However, is that possible from the border as well?

Comment: You mean as opposed to entering by air or sea? Or are you asking if the border crossing has an actual checkpoint and immigration office where you can get a visa?

Comment: I once crossed that border in a group, and if I remember correctly it was handled on-site.

Comment: @Flimzy Yes exactly. Or in other words I just wanted to make sure it can be handled there and I don't get turned back.

Comment: @Bernhard That is good enough for me. Thank you.

Comment: @EEBB Please cross check this, I am not 100% sure (otherwise I would have posted as an answer)

Comment: @EEBB what citizenship are you?

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible to get a visa on arrival at the border, driving / crossing in from Guatemala.

However, note that for many countries, [no visa is required](http://www.belize.com/belize-visa) for entrance. You can get a 90 day stay stamp basically without question.

For examples, stories, and pictures of the whole process, including some problems with border hopping, some bloggers have posted their experiences online, reenforcing that you can indeed get a visa on arrival.  Note, that it does depend on your country though, and you'll want to check the list above for yours.

Examples:

- [How to Cross the Guatemala – Belize Border. Plus, Meeting the Keystone Cops](http://antiguaguatemala.unwireme.com/how-to-cross-the-guatemala-belize-border-plus-meeting-the-keystone-cops/)
- [Travel From Guatemala to Belize](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/travel-guatemala-belize-32963.html)
- [Border Crossing: Melchor de Mencos (Gualemala/Belize)](http://kaypatadventures.wordpress.com/2014/07/31/border-crossing-melchor-de-mencos-gualemalabelize/)